# Nonlinear System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A point $p \in E$ is an $\omega$-limit point of the trajectory $\varphi(\cdot ,x)$ of the system $\dot{x} = f(x)$ if there is a sequence $t_n \to \infty$ such that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}⁡[\varphi(t_n,x) ]= p.$$
Similarly, if there is a sequence $t_n \to -\infty$ such that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}⁡[\varphi(t_n,x) ]= q,$$
 and the point $q \in E$, then the point $q$ is called an $\alpha$-limit point of the trajectory $\varphi(\cdot ,x)$ of the system $\dot{x} = f(x)$.

Sketch the phase portrait of a planar system having
i)  a trajectory $\Gamma$ with $\alpha(\Gamma)=\omega(\Gamma)=\{x_0\}$, but $\Gamma \not= \{x_0\}$.
ii) a trajectory $\Gamma$ such that $\omega(\Gamma)$ consist of one limit orbit and one equilibrium point.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset your question using latex/mathjax. It's really easy and makes the question so much easier to read.

Comment: please explain what are your thoughts on the problem and we will be happy to guide you with hints"

Comment: For part (i),  the solution should be a constant beacuse the limits are equal, but don't know how to sketch that.

Comment: But it says specifically that the trajectory where $\Gamma$ is constant is not allowed. Just because something has the same limit at $-\infty$ and $\infty$ does not mean it can't do anything else in-between.

Comment: that's correct.  still couldn't sketch the trajectory.